# PHP mail with include template path

Tags: include, if-statement, php

Trying to send a PHP email the easy way but I cannot work out why this one does not work. For some reason it sends 3 emails all with their entire content being '1' . That is all.

The PHP

```
else if (isset($_GET['quoteemail'])) {
$email = include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/bookings/booking-quote.php');

$to = $current_user->user_email;
  $subject = "Your Order - Dive The Gap" ;
  $message = $email;
  $headers = "From: Dive The Gap Bookings <ask@divethegap.com>" . "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

Don't worry about the else if, their is an IF or 2 before this function.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: Do the three e-mails go to different accounts? if you say `mail('me@co.com,you@co.com','subject','message')` it _will_ in fact send two emails =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include, that includes a file and tells you "1" when it successfully includes the file.

You probably want to look into the function: file_get_contents();

Comment: -1 In fact, if the included file has a `return` it returns that value.